# How to write rule to build object file when C files have different paths

Tags: makefile

I have bunch of C files, each with differnt path, so I have something like

```
SRC=/path1/path2/file1.c file2.c /usr/joe/files/file3.c
```

I want to build object file from each C file in build directory, so I did:

```
SRCBASE=$(notdir $(SRC))

OBJS= $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(SRCBASE:.c=.o))
```

This works fine, and I got the OBJS is build/file1.o build/file2.o build/file3.o

My question is how to write the implicit rule to build the object file, I tried to do:

```
build/%.o : %.c
gcc ....
```

But that seems now to work, since this rule did not catch the files with the full path.
I've tried to look at the gnu make, but did not find the answer there.

Many thanks.

Comment: The usual (sad) way with `make` is to have one `Makefile` per directory. Some tools (`autotools`, `cmake`) are generating `Makefile`-s for that purpose. You could use a better builder, like http://omake.metaprl.org/

Comment: What's wrong with your last snippet with pattern rule? It should work fine. Could you include the recipe into the question too?

Comment: Also, the way you construct `OBJS` seems to be wrong. You shouldn't get `notdir` of `SRC`, just replace the suffixes and prepend the objects direstory: `OBJS := $(SRC:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `VPATH` to locate files in other directories.  Note that this does implicit searches, though, rather than using explicit paths.  That is, you specify that you need file1.o through file3.o and that make should look first in `.`, then in `/path1/path2`, then in `/usr/joe/files`; so if . contains a `file3.c` you will get that one rather than the one in `/usr/joe/files` (or if not, but if there is one in `/path1/path2`, you will get that one).

It turns out that path searching is more often useful than explicit location anyway, so usually that's what you want.  If you need to override something you just copy or symlink the "desired version" to the first place to be searched.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I started with VPATH, but wanted to try to replace it with absolute paths. For the meanwhile, I think I'll keep with the VPATH.

Comment: Ther is also the `vpath` directive (lower-case) for GNU make.